# How to handle jitter buffer in pjsip/pjmedia framework?

Tags: multithreading, sip, rtp, pjsip

I have to handle rtp media for incoming and outgoing streams. The incoming stream is from different softphone and outgoing stream is to a diff phone. So its a media relay. For both streams I need to put them in jitter buffer and then play them out at constant bitrate. 
The framework is confusing me a bit. I am adding code in on_rx_rtp handler. I first break the payload into frames and put each frame in jitterbuffer. 
Now when and where do I get the frame?
In a different thread? or an event or in the same thread after the buffer is full to 70%?
Even if I do this, how do I combine the frames into a payload and then send them out? I have to use transport_send_rtp to send packets and not the intrinsic pjmedia stream or port framework?
Any help would be appreaciated.

Answer (score 1):

For media relay you may not need jitter buffer at all. Just send packet to receiver (B) immediately after receiving it from sender (A). You can assume that A is sending packets at correct rate and B has its own jitter buffer and forwarding packets immediately is not adding any significant delays (which is also downside of any buffering).

You may need jitter buffer if you need features like transcoding or being able to modify passed audio but then I would rather use pjmedia streams and conference bridge than handle each packet manually.

Comment: What if I receive packets out of order from sender A and need to resequence it? I was thinking that once I receive packets from sender A, I would buffer it and then it was when I became confused and as to when to get it. So I thought when I have filled up the buffer by 70% I would do a get_frame call but then I dont know how to combine the frames into a payload and send it coz there is a pjemdia_port_put_frame that can be used but since I am not using the pjmedia stream framework I cannot use that API. :(

Comment: Also, I would be receiving packets from sender B which is a receiver for A and A is a receiver for sender B. So its kind of RTP Forwarding with a relay agent. I don't think I can use the stream framework because it is rigid when it comes to forwarding. It has its own on_rx_rtp handler but I need to modify this very handler in order to relay packets

Comment: Should I create a manual port using pjmedia_port_create for putting a frame out?

Comment: Why would you need resequencing it? B should be able to do it on its own. Also, for plain media relay pjlib (e.g. activesock) may be enough - you may even not need information if packets are RTP (it may be UDP keepalive), just source address and address to forward packet to.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! Even if I am changing the RTP header(replacing SSRC) and then using encode_rtp to create a new header and send it, would it not need resequencing at all?

Comment: If you look at the stream API(pjmedia_stream) in stream.c, on receiving RTP Packet, it first adds it to a jitter buffer and then gets the frame in a separate playback thread so I thought it is necessary. Also, if the call breaks in between then we might need to buffer the data?

Comment: Media timings are typically driven by sound card - on each "tick" getpkt/putpkt functions are called, samples are taken out from jitter buffer (receiving side) and passed through conference bridge to be sent immediately. In media relay application I don't see the reason for using jitter buffer if this media relay does not need to listen or modify audio.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So if I need to do transcoding, I would want my SBC to do the jitter buffering then else not for relaying.